# What's the filter type of these ENB figures?

Tags: enb

In TI's "[Analog Engineer's Pocket Reference](http://www.docdroid.net/xjpc/analog-engineer039s-pocket-reference.pdf.html)" p. 45, it gives a table about the ENB (Equivalent Noise Bandwidth) of the filter with different poles count:

[image]

But it doesn't mention the filter type. I know the figures for a Butterworth lowpass filter are:

[image]

Is anyone familiar with the figures given in Table 15? Which filter type it use?

Comment: Can you provide a link that doesn't require a TI sign in?

Comment: [Analog Engineer's Pocket Reference](http://www.docdroid.net/xjpc/analog-engineer039s-pocket-reference.pdf.html)

Comment: This link http://www.millertechinc.com/pdf_files/TN129%20Equivalent%20Noise%20Bandwidth.pdf concurs with Andy : cascaded identical first order ("synchronous") filter sections. A bit sloppy of TI not to say so.

Comment: @BrianDrummond : Yes, this is my first time to hear that "synchronous filter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the table you are asking about is for a series of cascaded first order filters. These will naturally have a damping of unity and not be as good as a butterworth filter of n stages. [This](http://analog.intgckts.com/noise/equivalent-noise-bandwidth/) site calculates it for n = 2 and comes up with the figure of 1.22 as per your table. I suspect this applies to situations where n is greater than 2.